# reading US census products into R

Tags: r, census

I am trying to import the SIPP 2014 panel data into r but am having some trouble.

It can be found here: 
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/sipp/data/2014-panel/wave-1.html

Normally, this would be a pretty simple process and I could just use

```
data = read.csv("pu2014w1.dat")
```

The issue stems from the size of the dataset and the fact that I do not know what it is separated by nor how the column headers are done. Sadly, I cannot find documentation for importing this file into R.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `read.csv("C:/.../sipp_crosswalk_2014_2008.csv")` works for me...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the command works fine, its the data structure that I am uncertain of. I can use read.csv but the defaults in read.csv produce unintelligible data (due to the data not being separated by commas). The issue is that running read.csv on the dataset takes quite a bit of time to process. I plan on trimming the data to a more usable format but first I need to be able to load it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the file https://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/sipp/2014/pu2014w1.dat.gz

after unzipping, is a fixed-width format text file. So, to read it, we can use

```
library(readr)
read_delim("https://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/sipp/2014/pu2014w1.sas", 
       delim = " ", col_names = FALSE, skip = 6) -> foo
fwf_positions(start = foo$X4, end = foo$X6) -> bar
bar[ - c(5223:5231), ] -> bar2
bar3 <- bar2 %>% mutate(width = end - begin)

foobar <- fwf_widths(bar3$width)

read_fwf("pu2014w1.dat.gz", col_positions = foobar)
```

Note that when reading a fixed-width text file, we need to specify the positions of the fields. I do this by manipulating the contents of the sas input file, which tells us the positions of the fields (for use with SAS). Also, I had to download the gzipped file before I could successfully read it. Typically, I think, one can read directly from the url. I'm not sure why reading from the url didn't work here.